# Why doesn't `Cvs` CPAN module correctly recognize the status of already-checked-out file?

Tags: perl, cvs

Why doesn't [`Cvs`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Cvs) CPAN module (perl5.8, Cvs module version 0.06) correctly recognize the status of already-checked-out file?

```
$ echo $CVSROOT
:pserver:MYUSER@pserver.COMPANY.com:/u1/cvs_root

$ cvs co dev/script1.pl
U dev/script1.pl

$ cvs status dev/script1.pl | grep Status
File: script1.pl          Status: Up-to-date

$ cat cvs.pl

use Cvs; 
my $cvs = new Cvs("/u1/cvs_root",cvsroot => $ENV{CVSROOT}, password =>"****")
     or die $Cvs::ERROR; 
my $status = $cvs->status("dev/script1.pl"); 
print "STATUS: " . $status->status() . "\n"'

$ ./cvs.pl
STATUS: Needs Checkout
```

"Needs Checkout" is the status that CVS returns for valid CVS files that are NOT yet checked out. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

`cvs 0.06` is a really (>8 year) old module. Even the 0.07-release is almost 8 years old.
I don't use cvs myself, but I can imagine that there are numerous issues with such an old module...

Comment: The "perl5.8" part should have hinted at that as well :)   But my question is more on a technical level